# Regex to find links and sentences in wikipedia markup language

Tags: regex, scala

I intend to find sentences that contains link as a wiki markup language. So it should only have sentences that have [[.+]] as links.
A sentence in my case can be thought of words between to full stops (periods) or between the first word of the text to the next found full stop.

Example

> This is a [[link]] and a test. Also this [[link]] is what I want to
>   fetch. I dont want to fetch this line.

Expected output

> ```
> This is a [[link]] and a test.
> Also this [[link]] is what I want to fetch.
> ```

I have indpendent regex to detect links and sentences, just confused how to merge the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=[^.]*?\[\[[^\]]+\]\]).*?\.
```

This regexp give the whole sentence with the link by using [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Also it don't match sentence without link.

With Scala this makes an array with all sentence.

```
result = subject.scan(/(?=[^.]*?\[\[[^\]]+\]\]).*?\./)
```